# Swift 4 : Unable to convert Character to String

Tags: swift4

I'm extracting a number out of string of numbers in a character but unable either to convert that character to string or to int. Here is my code:

```
func processString(_ s: String) ->Bool {
    var sum = 0
    for char in s{
        let number = String(char){ //error Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Character, () -> ())'

        }
    }
}
```

if I try to converted to Int:

```
func processString(_ s: String) ->Bool {
    var sum = 0
    for char in s{
        let number = Int(String(char)){ //Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(String, () -> ())'

        }
    }
}
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or why can not convert the character to string or int?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have some extra `{ }` brackets in there that are not necessary. Removing those should solve the compiler issues.

```
func processString(_ s: String) ->Bool {
   var sum = 0
   for char in s{
      let charString = String(char)
      print(charString)
   }
}
```

On this next example, since the Int(_ string: String) initializer can return nil, you could use an `if let` statement to unwrap the result, which looks like what you may be trying to do with the `{ }`
It would look like this:

```
func processString(_ s: String) ->Bool {
    var sum = 0
    for char in s{
        if let number = Int(String(char)) {
            // number is not nil
        }
    }
}
```